# images uploaded to s3 via PaperClip not displaying in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a rails app that allows users to upload photos via paperclip to s3. While uploading works fine, when I try to display the image all I see is the image name...

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:thumbnail) %>
```

looking at the image properties the url is: http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/thumbnail/imagename.png?12982847

How do I make my image display in my rails app? 
and how do I change/hide the s3 url?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [ACL](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--access-control-list-details.html).

Regarding the domain, you can setup a CNAME domain (can be any domain) [which will point to your S3 bucket](http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3).

Answer (score 0):

are you using S3fox? if so, try setting the permissions on the folder so that anyone can read the file